# Are these correct event listener semantics?

Tags: javascript

All I'm going to do is simply hide a div when the button is clicked:

```
function hideDiv() {
    myDiv.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

the above function is say, a member of object `helpers`

If I do the following, I have to make sure the helpers object is created prior to this line. are there any other gotchas?:

```
buttonOK.addEventListener('click', helpers.hideDiv, false);
```

would it be better to do:

```
buttonOK.addEventListener('click', function () {helpers.hideDiv();}, false);
```

or need I pass in the event argument even though I don't use it?

```
buttonOK.addEventListener('click', function (event) {helpers.hideDiv();}, false);
```

or otherwise?

Comment: Use #1, there's no reason to make it longer.

Comment: The first one where the function is referenced is the correct syntax unless you need to pass arguments. The event is passed automatically, and they will all work just fine ?

Comment: Define "best practice". Better than what and by what criteria?

Comment: @Evan, I found that #1 can cause errors if the function is located in a module that hasn't been parsed yet.

Comment: Sure, you could say that about anything in Javascript. That's not obvious from your question.

Comment: best practice in terms of potential for bugs, code readability, and popular convention

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't calling hideDiv anywhere else, then I'd say the best practice would be using an anonymous function and not using the global namespace and using `this` to refer to the element that triggered the event:

```
buttonOK.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    myDiv.style.visiblity = 'hidden';
}, false);
```

---

There is no reason to use the extra function in this form:

```
buttonOK.addEventListener('click', function (event) {hideDiv();}, false);
```

unless you have to pass some custom parameters to `hideDiv()` which you do not here.  That extra function is just extra overhead and changes the calling pattern to hideDiv so that `this` will not be the element that trigger the event.

---

If you were using hideDiv in other event handlers too, then you could use:

```
function hideDiv(e) {
    myDiv.style.visiblity = 'hidden';
}

buttonOK.addEventListener('click', hideDiv, false);
buttonOK2.addEventListener('click', hideDiv, false);
buttonOK3.addEventListener('click', hideDiv, false);
```

Comment: but wont 'this' refer to the button? in which case the button would be hidden? rather than the div

Comment: @Dave - yes it would - I didn't realize that wasn't what you wanted - I changed it back to myDiv.

Answer (score 0):

The 'best practice' in this case mainly depends on what you are actually trying to do.
The best practice for your example is actually one you have not listed, and that is to do the hiding as part of the event handler:

```
buttonOK.addEventListener('click',function(){this.style.visibility='hidden'},false);
```

Do note though, that doing it this way automatically means your code requires the user to have a somewhat recent browser, as some older versions of Internet Explorer dont support addEventListener, and not all polyfills properly assign the `this` variable